# MVC3 Redirect Loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, https

I have been searching for a solution to this issue for over 10 hours with no answer. In my application I am using the [requirehttps] attribute.  When clicking an action method decorated with this attribute I get “cannot display the webpage" in IE.  After digging into that issue I saw that I was receiving infinite 302 calls in Fiddler, which would eventually timeout and cause that error.  So I decided to create a custom attribute and physically create the https call.  I am using IIS Express and successfully created a certificate and binded the port.  If I call this URL directly through the browser everything works fine.  This is the code I have been using to redirect the request.

```
public class HttpsAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute
{
public bool RequireSecure = false;

public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext){
  var builder = new UriBuilder(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url);

  if (RequireSecure){
    // redirect to HTTP version of page         
    builder.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
    builder.Port = 44300;
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(builder.Uri.ToString());
  }       
  else{         
    // non secure requested         
    if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection){             
      HandleNonHttpRequest(filterContext);         
    }       
  }    
}    

protected virtual void HandleNonHttpRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext){      
  if (String.Equals(filterContext.HttpContext.Request.HttpMethod, "GET", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){         
    // redirect to HTTP version of page         
    string url = "http://" + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Host + filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl;         
    filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);      
  }   
}
}
```

When I set a breakpoint to find out what the builder value is, it is correct.  And it is from here I receive an infinite redirect loop.  The strange thing is that the first request is never correct when I look at the URL within the browser.  It is as if UriBuilder is not sending the correct URL.  Any ideas?  This is driving me nuts.

Comment: What do you mean by infinite redirect loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The redirect loop is occurring because the code is only checking if the HTTPS redirect is required, not if the current request is already HTTPS (i.e. the redirect has already happened).

```
if (RequireSecure && !filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection){
  // redirect to HTTP version of page         
  builder.Scheme = Uri.UriSchemeHttps;
  builder.Port = 44300;
  filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(builder.Uri.ToString());
}       
else{         
  // non secure requested         
  if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsSecureConnection){             
    HandleNonHttpRequest(filterContext);         
  }       
}
```

Although the `RequireHttps` should work correctly for this, unless you need to redirect to the port specified.

EDIT:
Refactored attribute

```
public class HttpsAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.RequireHttpsAttribute
{
    public bool RequireSecure = false;

    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var requestUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;
        var requestIsSecure = HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection;

        if (RequireSecure && !requestIsSecure)
            filterContext.Result = Redirect(requestUri, Uri.UriSchemeHttps, 44300);
        else if (!RequireSecure && requestIsSecure)
            filterContext.Result = Redirect(requestUri, Uri.UriSchemeHttp, 80);

    }

    private RedirectResult Redirect(Uri uri, string scheme, int port)
    {
        return new RedirectResult(new UriBuilder(uri) { Scheme = scheme, Port = port }.Uri.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Brent thanks for the reply.  Before I created this custom attribute I was using RequiredHttps and still receiving a redirect loop.  When IE informs me that "There is a problem with this website's security certificate" and I click Continue, the URL within the browser is still http. After clicking continue the infinite redirect loop begins.  I added the additional condition check you mentioned, it does fix the redirect loop but now returns http instead of https.

Comment: @Aaron I was able to recreate the issue, my initial answer required a little more refactoring, I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks bud that worked. Really appreciate it.  Still not sure why the RequiredHttps sent me down this path.  I'm going to have to circle back and find out what was going on with that.